# Error resolving local package from node_modules during `next build dist` in monorepo

Tags: express, next.js, monorepo, lerna, preact

I would highly appreciated help with my problem.
Consider this simplified monorepo file structure:

```
| Frontend/
| -- common/
     | -- atoms/
          | -- package.json
          | -- index.ts
          ...
      ...
| -- app/
| -- web/
       | -- package.json
       | -- next.config.json
       | -- tsconfig.json
       | -- babel.config.json
        ...
       | -- server/
          | -- index.js
          ...
       | -- src/
          | -- components/
          | -- helpers/
          | -- pages/
          ...
       | -- dist/
          | -- components/
          | -- helpers/
          | -- pages/
          ...
       | -- node_modules/
          | -- @Common/
             | -- atoms/
```

`dist` directory is output from `babel --out-dir dist ./src`  terminal command, which uses specific inline babel configuration. It is needed to serve compliled components for my next.js server located in `web/server/index.js`. I need to keep this workflow to ensure access of compiled components before build to express next.js server.

Problem is that command `next build dist` over `web` directory is throwing a error:

> ModuleNotFoundError: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve
> '@Common/atoms' in
> '/Users/directory/directory/Frontend/web/dist/components/...' > Build
> error occurred Error: > Build failed because of webpack errors
> at /Users/directory/directory/Frontend/web/node_modules/next/dist/build/index.js:17:924
> at async Span.traceAsyncFn (/Users/directory/directory/Frontend/web/node_modules/next/dist/telemetry/trace/trace.js:6:584)

This is my code:
next.config.js

```
    const { resolve } = require('path')
    const toTranspile = require('./toTranspile')
    const withPlugins = require('next-compose-plugins')
    const withPreact = require('next-plugin-preact')

    const withTM = require('next-transpile-modules')('@Common/atoms', {
      resolveSymlinks: false,
      future: {
        webpack5: true,
      },
    })
    
    const config = {
      future: {
        webpack5: true,
      },
      webpack: (config, { dev, isServer, webpack, defaultLoaders }) => {

        if (defaultLoaders.babel.options.plugins === undefined) {
          defaultLoaders.babel.options.plugins = []
        }

       defaultLoaders.babel.options.plugins.push([
        'import',
         {
           libraryName: '@Common/atoms',
           libraryDirectory: '',
           transformToDefaultImport: false,
           camel2DashComponentName: false,
          },
         'atoms',
         ])
    
    
        const buildDir = dev ? 'src' : 'dist'
   
        const aliases = config.resolve.alias || (config.resolve.alias = {})
        aliases.lodash = resolve(__dirname, './node_modules/lodash-es')
    
        if (dev) {
          toTranspile.forEach((tmodule) => {
            aliases[tmodule] = resolve(__dirname, 'node_modules', tmodule)
          })
        }
    
        return config
      },
    }

module.exports = withPlugins([withPreact, withTM], config);
```

tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./src",
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": ["dom", "dom.iterable", "esnext"],
    "allowJs": true,
    "checkJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "strict": false,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "jsx": "preserve",
    "suppressImplicitAnyIndexErrors": true,
    "suppressExcessPropertyErrors": true,
    "downlevelIteration": true
  },

  "include": ["next-env.d.ts", "**/*.ts", "**/*.tsx"],
  "exclude": ["node_modules"]
}
```

babel.config.json

```
{
  "presets": ["next/babel"],
  "plugins": [
    [
      "module-resolver",
      {
        "root": ["./", "./graphql/"]
      }
    ]
  ]
}
```

What i have already tried:

- chaging compilerOptions.baseUrl in tsconfig.json
- changing `libraryDirectory` in next config `defaultLoaders.babel.options.plugins`
- changing alias in webpack next.config.js function

Comment: It looks like it's failing due to a lack of alias for `@Common/atoms`. I see you've set an alias for lodash, but it doesn't look like you have one for that package. Have you tried telling webpack about this alias?